# File Upload in SilverLight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, openfiledialog

HI
I Try Upload a file in Silver-Light. for doing this I use System.IO.File to read file bytes and then send the data to service to insert that data as file data in Database.
(Blow Code)

```
        byte[] data;
        OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
        open.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx";
        if (open.ShowDialog()==true)
        {
            open.File.OpenRead();
            data=System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(open.File.FullName);
            //---- send for service ---Service.savefileindatabase(data);
        }
```

so when use this code in line which include "ReadAllBytes" exception throw by VS, this is Exception Detail:
"File operation not permitted. Access to path '' is denied."
(for more info that file which i selected was in local Drive)

#### So What do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Silverlight there are far more restrictions than in usual wpf programming. The files you might upload may be only in specific directories and some methods are not available like `File.FullName`. Only a manually selected file might be uploaded. Your starting code is OK. But in silverlight you do not have access to paths (only to the name).

There are some `OpenText`, `OpenRead` methods which allow you to get a stream from the selected file. From that point you'll be able to do what you want with the data coming from the stream.

```
if (open.ShowDialog())
{
    using (StreamReader reader = open.SelectedFile.OpenRead())
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Great Help. also I want to know How write file (Download) in silver-Light.
Regards Rev

Comment: It's the same but you open a stream for writing. Maybe you are also interested in Isolated Storage here are answers that might interest you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753646/can-i-write-a-file-on-the-clients-pc-using-silverlight