# Call an aspx page in silverlight, without open it

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, system.net.httpwebrequest

I have, in my silverlight application, a call to a aspx page, to create and register a txt file on a directory.

```
Uri ub = (new Uri(HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri, "GenereInfos.aspx?&connexion=" + connexion + ";&id=" + this.Id));

        if (HtmlPage.IsPopupWindowAllowed)
        {
            HtmlPopupWindowOptions opt = new HtmlPopupWindowOptions();
            HtmlPage.PopupWindow(ub, "file", opt);
        }
        else
        {
            HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(ub);
        }
```

I have to go trough my aspx page to generate my txt file, because silverlight don't allow it.

The problem here is, a popup will appear, or the page will load the new uri.

What I want is call the code inside the asp only(which works perfectly), without loading the uri.

Is there a way to do this?

**Edit :** After DGibbs answer, there is another question now :

WShy can't I use GetResponse() in there?

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri
                     (HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri, "GenereInfos.aspx?&connexion=" + connexion + ";&idPocedure=" + itmProcedure.IdProcedure));
            string response = new System.IO.StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Here a little answer : Silverlight is asynchrnous, so, we can't call GetResponse who is synchronous.

So, the best way to call my aspx page, is to use WebClient [found here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/4ff41b4f-df41-4dad-8e41-fa653cb05174/getresponse-doesnt-work-in-silverlight)

Comment: Is it writing on a local or remote directory?

Comment: On a local, but I can also choose a remote directory (using a string is my aspx). For the moment, I get the myDocuments folder to put my txt file on it.

Comment: [Writing a File with Silverlight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753646/can-i-write-a-file-on-the-clients-pc-using-silverlight)

If this isn't your ultimate goal, let me know.

Comment: Yes indeed, writing a txt file in my final goal. But, how do I retrieve my txt file ? Do not found isolated storage location...

Comment: Where will you host the ASPX page? It won't be able to just write a file to the client.

Comment: It is on server side of my silverlight application. And like I said, it alrady works, but I don't won't to open or load a new page with the document uri.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0aa3d588%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri
                     (HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri, "GenereInfos.aspx?&connexion=" + connexion + ";&id=" + this.Id));
string response = new System.IO.StreamReader(req.GetResponse()
                 .GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: This doesn't go trough my aspx page.

Comment: I don't understand why I can't choose .GetResponse(), just have BeginGetResponse and EndGetResponse...

Comment: Just find out the response : it seems that in silverlight, WebClient is better for those calls : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/4ff41b4f-df41-4dad-8e41-fa653cb05174/getresponse-doesnt-work-in-silverlight

Comment: Well that was my original recommendation before the edit.. why couldn't you get it to work?

Comment: I don't know, it would'nt go trough it... I think that is it thanks to the completed method.